# getJSON code syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

Any thing wrong with this code? I get syntax error on line 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
               $("#button").click(function() {
               var url = 'http://www.foobar.com/?callback=?';

                params = { action: 'woocommerce_json_api', proc:"get_products"};
                params.arguments = {token: 1234, per_page: 10, page: 1}
                $.getJSON(url,params).done(function (data) {
                                                          console.log(data);
                                        });
                });
         });
    </script>
 <input type="button" id="button" value="test" />
 </body>
 </html>
```

I open firebug in firefox but I get syntax error on the console tab, anyone can spot the error?

Comment: Remove `});` in the last line at the end of your script block.

Comment: Code contained a small syntax error. Question is unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: what is the error in the console and what is the source line of the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checked for syntax errors, should be fine. take a look http://jsfiddle.net/ZdSm5/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        var url = 'http://www.foobar.com/?callback=?';

        params = { action: 'woocommerce_json_api', proc:"get_products"};
        params.arguments = {token: 1234, per_page: 10, page: 1};
        alert('works!');

        $.getJSON(url,params).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra pair of `})` at the bottom of the script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var url = 'http://www.foobar.com/?callback=?';

        params = { action: 'woocommerce_json_api', proc:"get_products"};
        params.arguments = {token: 1234, per_page: 10, page: 1}
        $.getJSON(url,params).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note: Try to use a proper IDE for development as it can point out silly errors like this easily

Comment: There is ALSO the missing semi colon, as Fabien points out, but this one is why you get the syntax error. Semi-colons in javascript SHOULD be optional (though it depends which browser you're using as to whether they actually will be).

Comment: My bad, I for got  to put "$("#button").click(function() {" after my ready function. Updated the post.

Comment: Codelobster points these out to me all the time.